# What is "short-circuiting" in C like languages?

Tags: concepts, conditions, if-statement

I have heard of the term "short-circuiting" being used in C, C++, C#, Java, and many others. What does this mean and in what scenario would it be used?

Comment: There is a Wikipedia Article about the concept: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation It is an optimization in the evaluation of the `&&` operator.

Comment: @wirrbel I believe it applies to `||` as well... at least it should.

Comment: @RaduMurzea Indeed. Contrast `||` and `&&` to `&` and `|` to see the subtle difference. Have a simple program evaluate `1 || printf("yay");` vs `0 || printf("yay");` and `1 | printf("yay");` vs `0 | printf("yay");` to see the differeces

Answer (score 43):

Short circuiting in C is when a logical operator doesn't evaluate all its arguments.

Take for example and `&&`, it's pretty obvious that `0 && WhoCares` is going to be false no matter what `WhoCares` is. Because of this, C just skips evaluating `WhoCares`. Same goes for `1 || WhoCares`, it'll always be true. Because of this, we can write code like

```
CanFireMissiles && FireMissiles()
```

This way we avoid doing some potentially impossible operation. If we can't fire the missiles we certainly don't want to try to. This is commonly used with pointers, especially file pointers.

```
 bool isN(int* ptr, int n){
     return ptr && *ptr == n;
 }
```

This plays out in lots of other useful ways to avoid unnecessary computing

```
 isFileReady() || getFileReady()
```

This avoids doing extra work if we don't need to.

Comment: Anytime, if I've answered your question you can check the checkbox beside it to mark your question as answered

Comment: I don't love `CanFireMissiles && FireMissiles()`, as it makes me suspect you're abusing short-circuiting to trigger side effects.  I feel like you're hiding actions in a conditional.  Such code is better written as `if(CanFireMissiles){FireMissiles();}` or `if(CanFireMissles){didFireMissiles = TryFireMissiles(); if(didFireMissiles){...}}`.

Comment: I'd argue that the only use is to hide side effects. Usually not the the "Blowing up a city" sort but things like dereferencing a pointer or using system resources are also done in this manner in C quite often. See the wikipedia page, the whole section under usage is "Hiding side effects"

Comment: @jozefg you can also use it to prevent doing expensive operations like `IsInCache(value) || IsInDatabase(value)`, where IsInDatabase might take time (especially if using a mobile device and network latency is an issue).

Answer (score 4):

"Short Circuiting" typically refers to "[Short Circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)" which is a general concept, not just C specific.

Boolean operators evaluation left to right, so any terms that will render the other terms unnecessary are useful. So you might check for a condition that excludes other conditions later on, thus allowing a partial evaluation of the logical operations rather than evaluating the whole thing.

Example:

```c
while((x && y) == 1) {
    //This bit will not execute if x is 0 or y is 0 but y won't even be 
    //evaluated due to short circuit evaluation if x is 0.
}
```

A more complex example:

```c
if((a || b || c || d || e || f || g || h || i || j || k) == 1) {
    /* If any of these are equal to 1 the whole expression is equal to 1,
     * thus doesn't it make sense to short circuit evaluate this?
     * Saves a bunch of time.
     */
}
```

Comment: Short circuiting is less about saving time but more about not being evaluated. A function not being evaluated will also not have the side effect would it be evaluated.

Comment: You know, the `== 0` is not only unneccessary, it might actually confuse some people.

Answer (score 3):

[Short ciruit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) can lead to some parts of a condition not be evaluated.

For example:

```
if (true || f()) { ... }
```

will not exectue `f`.